# proxy server works when vpn is on?

Tags: java, netty, proxy-server

I wrote proxy server with netty and I used this tutorial https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy, I mean, I just copy/paste proxy example and the problem is when I start VPN of my windows and then I run the proxy server it works well, but when VPN is off the proxy server just read requests and can not send any data to the browser. for example when I run localhost: port in the browser if VPN is on I got a response from a remote server which is shown in the browser but when VPN is off I can not see anything on the browser and when I check the logs the number of written bytes is zero.
My netty version is 4.1.51.